# How to insert data with create in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

How to insert data with create in Django

thank you

Model

```
class Cliente(models.Model):

    seguimento          = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Form

```
class ClienteForm(forms.Form):

    seguimento = forms.IntegerField()

    def create(self, validated_data):

        client = Cliente.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

view

```
form = ClienteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.create(validated_data=request.POST)
```

Errors:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

TypeError at /admin/cliente
Field 'seguimento' expected a number but got [3].

Comment: You have to use `form.cleaned_data`. It's safer. So:  `form.create(form.cleaned_data)`

Comment: It`s work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do in order to save the form is calling `form.create(form.cleaned_data)` if the form is validated successfully. Read more on [form-cleaned_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#field-data).

```
form = ClienteForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # use form.cleaned_data instead of request.POST
    form.create(form.cleaned_data)
```

Comment: This works with modelForm. However, I'm not using it. I'm using forms.Form. Thank you

Comment: I see, it looks like your form is being validated for list[int] and then model is not accepting that as a valid input.

Comment: @marcelo.delta passing `form.data` inside create should work.

request.POST is a dict like object called `QueryDict ` and accept inputs from the html forms as lists.

Comment: form.create(validated_data=form.data) - Does not work

Comment: @marcelo.delta I think the attribute name is `cleaned_data` on forms. I am so used to work with DRF serializers. Hope this works.